# Listing "Publications" in CV - How to list multiple co-authored book chapters from one single Book?

Tags: publications, cv, books, doi

I have co-authored 2 book chapters on two different topics under 1 Book Title.
The Book has a single editor (but not co-author to these chapters), one ISBN and one DOI number. The chapters do not have individual ISBN or DOI.

So, when I listed the book chapters in my CV, both the listed items have same ISBN and DOI.

- Should I list the 2 book chapters under a *single* item or as *separate* items?

  > SINGLE ITEM
  >
  > > [1] (a) Authors. Book chapter 1. ISBN: XYZ-1234-ABC. DOI: 10.1234/XYZ
  > >      (b) Authors. Book chapter 2. ISBN: XYZ-1234-ABC. DOI: 10.1234/XYZ

  > SEPERATE ITEMS
  >
  > > [1] Authors. Book chapter 1. ISBN: XYZ-1234-ABC. DOI: 10.1234/XYZ
  > > [2] Authors. Book chapter 2. ISBN: XYZ-1234-ABC. DOI: 10.1234/XYZ
- Should I keep ISBN and DOI with the publications?

Answer (score 1):

The contribution type here is "book chapter", and you have two of them. Thus, you should list two separate items. Even if the doi is pointing to the entire book rather than the individual chapter, it still seems useful, thus you should include it. I see no problem with having the same doi listed for two items (other than that a careful reader might suspect a copy&paste error, but anyone who actually follows it will understand).

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon to list separately. However, in your scenario, the single list might work for DOIs that are not distinct for each chapters.

Nonetheless, if I were in your shoes, I'll engage with the publisher about having separate/distinct DOI for each chapters.
Normally, chapters DOI are separated with an underscore. For instance,
Book DOI:10.1234/xyz
Chap 1 DOI: 10.1234/xyz_1
Chap 2 DOI: 10.1234/xyz_2

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that on a CV you actually have quite a bit of freedom on how to structure items, so personally I might go with

1. TITLE/EDITOR/IBSN

- chapter 1
- chapter 2

So 1 item and then the chapters detailed without individual ISBNs.

Of course it also depends on your CV - if you don't have a lot of publications yet, you might prefer more items.

Comment: Is it advisable if I list them as separate publications with the ISBN, but without DOI?
I intend to remove the DOI completely to avoid any kind of confusion.

Comment: Both ISBNs and DOIs serve as identifiers, it is totally fine to list both, they are well known and nobody would be confused (the ISBN just signals "book").